# Angular, Chart.js animation inside mat-tab

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am displaying few charts in mat-tab and I don't have an animation of showing data in the chart.

```
animation: {
           duration: 1000,
           easing: 'easeOutQuart'
       }
```

Outside the mat-tab animation works, but inside is only final effect (animation time nothing changes). Try to use onComplete() and it's fire after time I set, but theres no animation. I am also using ngx-charts. Any solutions?

chart.ts

```
public chartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: false
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes:
                [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function (dataLabel, index) {
                            if ([0, 5, 11, 17, 23].indexOf(index) !== -1) {
                                return dataLabel;
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                            // return (index + 1) % 3 === 0 ? dataLabel : null;
                        },
                        autoSkip: false,
                        maxRotation: 0,
                        padding: 10,
                        fontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    padding: 10,
                    min: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 100
                },
                gridLines: {
                    drawTicks: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.04)'
                }
            }]
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'easeOutQuart'
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: (item, data) => `${item.yLabel} ${data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].label}`,
                title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                    return `Godzina: ${data.labels[tooltipItems[0].index]}`;
                },
            }
        }
    };
```

chart.html

```
<div class="chart-area">
    <canvas baseChart
            [chartType]="'bar'"
            [datasets]="[chartConfig.chartData]"
            [labels]="chartConfig.chartHours"
            [options]="chartConfig.chartOptions"
            [colors]="[chartConfig.chartColors]">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: put more code of your chart creation, this animation object is inside options?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a library, personally i use [ngx-chartjs](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-chartjs), because it have the `chartInstance` with only doing `this.chart.chartInstance` and you can use it for outside methods like printing..

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: if you remove `easing: 'easeOutQuart'`?

Comment: Of course there is no animation when i removed it. Problem is the animation is not done when the chart is inside of mat-tab. If i put the component outside of mat-tab everything is okay.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `<ng-template matTabContent>`

It wiil look something like that:

```html
<mat-tab label="example">
   <ng-template matTabContent>
    <div class="chart-area">
      <canvas baseChart
            [chartType]="'bar'"
            [datasets]="[chartConfig.chartData]"
            [labels]="chartConfig.chartHours"
            [options]="chartConfig.chartOptions"
            [colors]="[chartConfig.chartColors]">
      </canvas>
    </div>
   </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

You can read more about Lazy loading [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)